# Как вернуть id созданной или обновлённой записи? SQLite Unity

Tags: c#, sql, база-данных, unity3d, sqlite

У меня получается обновить или создать в базе запись, вот только мне надо ещё вернуть значение в колонке `"id"`. Как это сделать?

Мой код:

```
public void UpdateSELECTObj(string sqlQueryStringUpdateObj) {
    Debug.Log("sqlQueryStringUpdateObj="+sqlQueryStringUpdateObj);
    connectionString = "URI=file:"+Application.dataPath+"/TerrainTools/db/object.sqlite";
    using (IDbConnection dbConnection = new SqliteConnection(connectionString)) {
        dbConnection.Open();
        using(IDbCommand dbCmd = dbConnection.CreateCommand()) {
            dbCmd.CommandText = sqlQueryStringUpdateObj;
            using (IDataReader reader = dbCmd.ExecuteReader()) {
                // while(reader.Read()) { 
                //     if (!reader.IsDBNull(reader.GetOrdinal("id"))) {
                //         Debug.Log("reader.GetInt16(0)="+reader.GetInt16(0));
                //         //reader.GetInt16(0);
                //     } else {
                //         Debug.Log("nuLL");
                //     }
                // }
                dbConnection.Close();
                reader.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Сама таблица в SQLite:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
как мне вернуть значение в колонке id_ObjM обновлённой или созданной записи?
передаю я строку в мою функцию такую :

```
string stringupdate = "UPDATE ObjectMap SET db_name = '"+stringTextFieldShortName+"', db_geometry_type = "+selectTGvalue+",db_layer_number = "+selectLayervalue+" WHERE db_key = '"+stringTextFieldKey+"'";


void SaveInBDObj(string stringupdate) {
    ODBtemp = new ObjectDataBase();
    ODBtemp.UpdateSELECTObj(stringupdate);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Во-первых, используйте параметры. Не используйте конкатенацию строк для построения sql-запросов.

Для получения последнего вставленного id используйте функцию [last_insert_rowid()](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#last_insert_rowid). Сделать это можно так:

```
dbCmd.CommandText = @"INSERT INTO [ObjectMap] (db_key) values (@key);
                      SELECT last_insert_rowid();";

dbCmd.Parameters.Add("@key", DbType.String).Value = "some key";

var id = (long)dbCmd.ExecuteScalar();
```

Одним запросом вставляем (`insert`) и тут же получаем (`select`) нужные данные.

---

При выполнении `update` айдишник не меняется. Не вижу смысла получать его.

Answer (score 0):

на сколько я понял у вас поле id_ObjM автоматом увеличивается на 1 при добавлении записи следовательно после того как вы добавили запись вам нужно сформировать запрос по тем параметрам которые вы вводили при добавлении или обновлении записи.

```
string stringupdate = "SELECT id_ObjM FROM ObjectMap WHERE db_name ='stringTextFieldShortName' AND db_geometry_type = 'selectTGvalue' AND db_layer_number ='selectLayervalue' AND db_key='stringTextFieldKey';"
```